# NHibernate 3 - How to perform a LIKE on an id/numeric/int

Tags: queryover, nhibernate-3

Whilst SQL Server is perfectly comfortable doing:

```
where Id like '45%'
```

(id being an int), NH will complain as it will still try to send the compare value into sql as a SqlParameter of type int when doing:

```
q.WhereRestrictionOn(cl => cl.CompanyId).IsLike(companyIdFilter)
```

So how to get round it with the new QueryOver API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some digging around and and trial and error, this does the trick:

```
q.Where(Expression.Like(
   Projections.Cast(
     NHibernateUtil.String,
     Projections.Property<ChangeLog>(cl => cl.CompanyId)), 
   companyIdFilter.Value.ToString(),  
   MatchMode.Start
));
```